# How to fetch resource thorugh Expo/React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, expo

Using this code:

```js
 handleShortCapture = async () => {
      try {
        const photoData = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
        this.setState({ capturing: false, captures: [photoData, ...this.state.captures] })
      } catch (e) {
        ToastAndroid.show(e)
      }

      const shibeAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
      Speech.speak(`shibe amount: ${shibeAmount}`)

      try {
        const shibes = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://shibe.online/api/shibes?count=${shibeAmount}urls=false&httpsUrls=false`)
        const jsonShibes = await shibes.json()
        Speech.speak(jsonShibes.length)
      } catch(e) {
        Speech.speak(e.message)
      } 
    };
```

I can hear the *shibe amount* phrase but can't hear the response from the **fetch** request; What am I missing?

Comment: Firstly, add a `try-catch` block enclosing `await` call (since it deals with a Promise, maybe you're getting a warning of unhandled Promise rejection!)

Comment: @SagarKulkarni added your suggestion in it